# ArrayAdapter - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity that I'm trying to bind to an array of business objects using a custom ArrayAdapter.

When I run the application on either the emulator or the real android device I get a null reference in the ArrayAdapter on the line "holder.txtTeam1.setText(info.Team1);".  After doing some debugging it looks like the call to inflate the layout didn't actually create the child TextViews, it only created the outter TableLayout.

This is all based on a tutorial I found on the internet, and I've been banging my head off the desk for almost a week on this one.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The activity looks like this:

```
    public class BaseballPressActivity extends ListActivity {

    private GameDataAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new GameDataAdapter(this, new GameData[]{new GameData("3:10pm","Team 1","Team 2")});
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

The ArrayAdapter looks like this:

```
public class GameDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameData> {

Context context;
GameData data[] = null;

public GameDataAdapter(Context context, GameData[] data) {
    super(context,R.layout.listitem_game, R.id.Name1, data);

    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    GameViewHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test , parent, false);

        holder = new GameViewHolder();
        holder.txtTeam1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Name1);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (GameViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    GameData info = data[position];
    holder.txtTeam1.setText(info.Team1);

    return row;
}

static class GameViewHolder
{
    TextView txtTeam1;
    TextView txtTeam2;
    TextView txtGameTime;
}

}
```

And the layout for the list activity item looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_weight="0" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="0dp"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="0dp"></ImageView>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/Name1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/Name2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_width="0dp"></ImageView>
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Yashwanth Kumar gets credit for the answer, and Dan S gets an upvote for giving me a more simple solution and showing me something I didn't know about.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i think the problem is here

```
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test , parent, false);
```

change false to true, i think you have to attach the view to it's parent.

if that doesn't work try this.

```
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test , null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Abandon ArrayLayout for [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). This will allow you to easily bind your data with simple to fairly complex layouts.

Comment: That's what I tried doing before, but it looked like the SimpleAdapter only allowed me to bind one property of the business object to one view in the layout.  When this is fully working I will actually need to bind 5 views in the LayoutItem to different fields in the business object.  I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Using the `from` and `to` parameters in the constructors you can bind an arbitrary number of data items to views.